# Cell borders are incomplete on print preview

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing

Something super odd is happening with a spreadsheet I inherited from a colleague. I have borders all around numerical values, but not all of it shows up on print preview:

[image: Screenshot of the print preview]

Everything prints properly, though! I'm just really curious why it's doing that.

Also, there are grid lines that appear on a second page when printing.

Phantom grid lines here:
[image: ScreenShot of phantom grid lines]

I've tried clearing, deleting, etc., (which worked on some lines on the first page), but it refuses to go away. Is there a way to get rid of it?

Comment: The print preview render often doesn't display the gridlines correctly. I've found zooming in on the print preview will often make them show up.

Comment: If you are struggling with Grid Lines, (Bcoz in the attached Screen Shot I can see the BORDERS around) then do this,, Click `Page Layout`, in `Sheet Option` find `Grid Lines` check `Print` option. You find Grid lines appears during Print Preview also. ☺

Comment: Wow, I never knew one can zoom in on the print preview--thanks for that tidbit! Most of the borders do render when I zoom in on print preview, but some of them still don't. Oh well, as long as it prints properly!                         Also, I figured out how to get rid of the phantom borders (they were just on a different pane, haha), but the 2nd blank page still wants to print.

Comment: You probably have something in a cell below.  It could be just a space in one cell.  You can try deleting unused rows below or set the Print Area in Page Setup::Sheet.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I do, and its settled my problem

1. hightlight the missing line area
2. right click --> format cells --> tab border
3. then at border -- click text -- then the line will appear
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hj9Dm.png)
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfhD3.png)

there yo go.

Comment: I think the OP's problem is that lines that are really there don't show in the shrunken print preview (pixel rounding).

Answer (score 0):

Just click on print option on page set up go to sheet and click black and white. This will solve the cell lines from not printing.